# Get Google Ads customer id via login

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api, google-signin

I use “google-ads-api” to manage google ads. And api needs “customer_account_id” to initialization. However, I Couldn’t found how to get “customer_account_id” programmatically from user.

I used “react-google-login” in front-end, but there is no “customer_account_id” in the response. What is the best way to get customer_account_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use the `CustomerService`'s `ListAccessibleCustomers` method. This request does not require a `customer_account_id` and you can use it to obtain all Google Ads account IDs that the authenticated user has access to.
See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/account-management/listing-accounts) for details.

I believe that in `google-ads-api` the relevant class is called [`AccessibleCustomersService`](https://github.com/Opteo/google-ads-api/blob/master/src/services/accessible_customers.ts).